# How to run an executable in bash if name has spaces?

Tags: bash

I am running bash from Cygwin on Windows. I would like to run an executable program in another directory than the one I am in, but there seems to be a problem if the directory name contains spaces. I can run the exe from its own directory (C:/someUser/myPrograms/Project Name With Spaces/) with no problem,

```
./myFile.exe
```

But if I am in another directory (/cygdrive/c) and try to run the executable with the full directory path, it doesn't seem to work even if I double quote the name to deal with the spaces,

```
./"C:/someUser/myPrograms/Project Name With Spaces/myfile.exe"
-bash: ./C:someUser/myPrograms/Project Name With Spaces/myfile.exe: No such file or directory
```

If I replace ./ with ls it has no problem finding the executable, so I know I am entering the correct path name.

Is there another way to run the executable that can handle the full name with spaces?

Comment: The "./" usually refers to the current directory. What directory are you in? From the path and the file extension, it looks like you are running on Windows. What are you using to run bash? e.g. Cygwin? "Git Bash Here"?

Comment: The above comment should be answered if you want to know the best practice for your `bash` implementation/emulation. In general either the implementation understands windows paths and accept them as commands and you would just need to remove the leading `./` (example : `git-bash`) or it doesn't and you should use a more idiomatic way to address your executable (example : `Cygwin`, which generally understands quoted windows paths but refuse to accept them as commands). There are multiple other implementations so a generic answer isn't easy to produce.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that the implementations would differ! I edited the question to reflect that I am running it from Cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cygwin, you would want one of

```
"/cygdrive/c/someUser/myPrograms/Project Name With Spaces/myfile.exe"
/cygdrive/c/someUser/myPrograms/Project\ Name\ With\ Spaces/myfile.exe
"$(cygpath -u "C:\someUser\myPrograms\Project Name With Spaces\myfile.exe")"
```

Comment: These both work, thanks. [Sorry to all that I did not initially specify Cygwin: I think the other answers are likely correct for 'real' bash implementations].

Comment: but what if the filename is in a variable?

Comment: You make sure you quote the variable: `unixdir="$(cygpath -u "$windir")"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote it:

```
'some cmd'
```

Better make sure that your executable names and the paths to it does *not* contain whitespace.

---

But the problem here is you're misunderstanding the `.` It means *the current directory*. Since the path you are running is *not* a subfolder of the current folder - remove the `./` in front.

Answer (score 1):

You can use escaping, for spaces: `'\ '`